# Problema con acentos y caracteres especiales al emplear el metodo get

Tags: html, rest, symfony, php7, get

Estoy trabajando en una API Rest con Symfony 2.8. Se me ha dado el caso siguiente: cuando hacen una petición a la URL `/search`, normalmente llega esto:

```
http://{servidor.com}/search/libros?q=vacaciones&language=es
```

la petición la manejo en el controller de esta manera:

```
public function searchAction($elemento, ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher){
    $q = $paramFetcher->get('q');

    // ... demas proceso, haciendo consulta a bbdd
```

Recientemente me he encontrado con que me hacen esta petición:

```
http://{servidor.com}/search/libros?q=democr%C3%A1tico&language=es
```

y cuando hago un var_dump($q) en el controlador, me encuentro que $q vale **democrÃ¡tico**.

Esto tiene pinta de ser un problema de conversión de caracteres, de utf8 o de algo parecido.

Por supuesto, entiendo que la petición es incorrecta, pero me han pedido que mientras tanto, corrija en mi aplicación este problema. Sin embargo, no encuentro forma de configuración o de conversión. Además, aunque en la petición vale `democr%C3%A1tico`, cuando llega al controlador ya está transformado con los caracteres `Ã¡`.

Supongo que se puede cambiar la configuración del FosRestBundle pero en la [documentación oficial](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/configuration-reference.html) no aparece nada al respecto de utf8. ¿A alguien le suena este problema? ¿Podéis ayudarme?

Answer (score 0):

En el caso que me ocupa, el framework ya utiliza internamente la codificacion de urldecode para obtener el objeto Request, que es que utilizo para obtener los parametros.

Mi problema aqui ha sido otro, la configuracion del servidor nginx no tenia en cuenta la codificación utf-8. Le he añadido en la linea de configuracion:

```
charset: UTF8;
```

Y una vez reiniciado el servidor la aplicación ha respondido correctamente.